# How to filter duplicate values in list comprehension in python without using a set

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have to filter duplicate values in list comprehension

```
 with open(file_name, 'rU') as input_file:          
        result = [unique for unique in [process(line) for line in input_file] if **unique_not_in_generated_list**]
```

What expression could be used instead of **unique_not_in_generated_list**?

python 2.7

Comment: Why the aversion to a set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) like this

```
from itertools import groupby
print [unique for unique, _ in groupby(sorted(process(line) for line in input_file))]
```

**Note:** This doesn't maintain the Order of the data, but guranteed to generate unique items without using sets.

Comment: He refrains from set, probably because he doesn't want to change the order. Sorting un-does it.

Comment: Wouldn't the sorting kill the line ordering, though/

Comment: @Thrustmaster Thats not explicitly mentioned in the question :(

Comment: @inspectorG4dget It will, but the OP hasn't mentioned anything specifically about it :(

Comment: @thefourtheye Right, but this is simply a workaround for not using `set`; may be even less efficient. OrderedDict.fromkeys may work for the OP, like in my answer.

Comment: @Thrustmaster +1 Thats the best one :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a one liner to remove duplicates while keeping the lines ordered. Use [`collections.OrderedDict`'s `fromkeys`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections#ordereddict-objects)

```
result = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(process(line) for line in input_file))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a generator expression and `set()`:

```
with open(file_name, 'rU') as input_file:          
    result = list(set(process(line) for line in input_file))
```

If you need to retain the ordering, you can still use set. I also sacrifice the list comprehension in favor of readability:

```
result = list()
seen = set()

with open(file_name, 'rU') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        unique = process(line)
        if unique not in seen:
            seen.add(unique)
            result.append(unique)
```

If you insist on using list comprehension and keeping order, you can do this by using a throwaway list of `None`s, but this sort of defeats the purpose and is **O(N^2)**

```
result = list()
with open(file_name, 'rU') as input_file:
    [result.append(x) for process(x) in input_file if process(x) not in result]
```